# Trouble with void * casting to int syntax

Tags: c++, void-pointers

This function checks if the first parameter is even, and if it is, adds that value to the second parameter. It uses void * and I have to convert to an int but I am having trouble with the syntax and how to properly cast, and use the pointers.

```
bool isEven(void *x, void* z) {

int * a = (int *)x;
int * b = (int *)z;

bool result = false;

if (*a % 2) {

    result = true;
    b += a;
}

return result;
}
```

What is wrong with my syntax? I get an error under 'a' saying "expression must have integral or enum type"

Comment: At least `b += a` line is wrong.

Comment: Since `a` and `b` are pointers, and assuming you want to add `a` to `b`, you would need `*b += *a`. You should at least attempt to learn the **syntax** of a language before asking about it on SO - we are not a "teach me language X" site.

Comment: Why are you using void* instead of just int

Comment: In C++ you would **never write such code** like `bool isEven(void*x, void*z);` because there is no use for it. The only use for such ugly code is when using some old C code. As this is unavoidably very error prone, try to avoid that.

Comment: Not only that, but this function doesn't do what it says it does. This should definitely be refactored into two different methods.

I would never expect a function named isEven to modify the variables.

Answer (score 6):

Your addition does not modify the integers, but the pointers. But pointers cannot be added.

Do instead:

```
*b += *a;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to add one pointer to the other which is illegal operation in C++. You need to dereference the pointers first to use integers they are pointing to (if that is your intention in the first place):

`*b += *a;`

Comment: Ah ok, how would I dereference the pointer, so that I would use it?